# Put user's comment into his question?

Tags: discussion, edits, comments

If I ask a user for more information, and he leaves a comment with that information, can I edit his response into his question?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Provided the OP does not do so himself, yes. All necessary information should be in the question itself, making it easier for answerers and readers to understand the issue without wading through possibly long comment chains.

Comment: The problem with that is the code that was placed in the comments (which is probably unreadable) needs to be deleted. Most folks performing such an edit cannot delete the comment. Flagging will likely be rejected, which means you will likely land on a ban list for a while. I think its best to teach the user how to use the site properly.

Comment: @jww - The comment doesn't HAVE to be deleted, though it is often nice if it is done.  And in some cases the comment should be left, since other comments may reference it and the time order may be relevant.

Comment: @jww - In my experience, flagging comments that have made their way back into the OP as obsolete has been very constructive. I'm not sure I've ever had one like that declined.

Comment: I often take their comment, edit their post and then _post a comment_ explaining what I did and how to edit their own question. I find that after this, sometimes the OP will delete their own comment (assuming the time limit hasn't elapsed).

Comment: I agree with @BradWerth. Edit the comment in with a clear edit description that says it was information provided in comments, wait to be approved (if necessary), then flag the comment(s) as obsolete. I get "obsolete" flags approved all the time.

Answer (score 27):

I usually ask the OP to edit in to their own question so that they learn to do that in future. Or if I edit it in, I will notify them in comments that I have done it and why it should be done.

The emphasis I guess is on teaching them that information that is important to the post and future viewers should be in plain site in the main post body.

Comment: .. as well as that [comments are second-class citizens](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comments) and may be removed at will.